# How can I install Magento freshly without sample data?

Tags: installation

I followed the steps here to install a fresh magento - Installing Magento With The Full Download: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

I created an empty database, then went to the web interface (http://www.mydomain.com/magentoroot/) for the initial setup.

During the setup process, after I input the database information, the next page always gave me an error like the following:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:221:"Error in file: "***/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity' already exists";i:1;s:1036:"#0 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0.8')
#2 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0.8')
#3 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(412): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 ***/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(338): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 ***/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 ***/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:36:"/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

If I imported the sample data before going to the web interface for the initial setup, there would be no error.

But I don't want the sample data, I just want a clean Magento. Below is some more information:

- Trying to install 1.9.1 and 1.9.0.1
- This is a dedicated server. I created a clean development account---neither Magento nor anything else installed there before.
- Run on PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5
- CGI/FastCGI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can check your database? It seems that there already are tables which Magento tries to create. Make sure that your browser doesn't timeout during database installation: if so then it will be terminated and on retry, there will be already partly installed data which will cause the error you posted (or similar).

If that is the issue, turn it off. In [Firefox](http://morgb.blogspot.de/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html) you should put 0 in the config field mentioned in post I linked to. Personally, I didn't run into such an issue with other browsers.

Anyway, clean your database first: remove all the tables created or just create new database and try to install. If the process will hang and you'll have this error again, then check if your browser's timeout setting is not an issue.

**EDIT:** After information about 500 internal server errors you prvoded in the comment, it may be FastCGI issue, like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146184/i-get-500-internal-server-error-after-30-seconds-of-running-a-script).

Comment: Database was clean since I created it right before installing magento. And I did use Firefox. That gave me some hope now. I'll try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @Shawn Then it might be browser issue. It would explain why the tables turn out to be already created when installing on clean one. The process must have been terminated and ran again which may be beacuse of your web browser's timeout.

Comment: I'll just try on Chrome, then. You said other browsers had no such issue, right?

Comment: At least in Chromium I had no such issue. In Firefox: only with few versions. Windows one (don't remember the number), and recently with Firefox 31.3.0.

Comment: I tried on Chrome but still had the error.... =( Any idea?

Comment: But what happens? It hangs during the database installation at blank screen? Or you get the error message? Maybe your user you pass to Magento have some limited privileges? (limited queries amount?) If your installation hangs at blank screen, try again with FF, open `about:config` in your browser, go to `network.http.response.timeout` and set it to `0`. Then try again and don't forget to clear your database.

Comment: I found that on my server if a php script runs over 30 seconds, the server throws a 500 error. This is weird since from phpinfo.php the max_execution_time is set to 18000. I'm contacting my hosting company for a solution. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: So, it might be FastCGI issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146184/i-get-500-internal-server-error-after-30-seconds-of-running-a-script). I hope you'll finally solve your problem. :)

Comment: You are right!! Thank you very much. Since the answer is in the comment, can I accept this as the answer? I'm pretty new to the stack exchange.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to my previous comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message "`SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity' already exists`" means your database already has some Magento tables in it.

Are you sure you cleared the database completely before trying without sample data?

Comment: Yes. I created the database right before going to the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Check local.xml file in your installation directory.
It can be found in app->etc
Here we declare the database name which is to be used for Magento.
Check this if it contain the same name.
Else try truncating all the data from DB and install from starting.